# Hasura Authentication Passport.js Auth Webhook does not work

Tags: docker, graphql, apollo-client, hasura

I tried to use the Passport.js Auth Webhook Boilerplate [here](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/tree/master/community/boilerplates/auth-webhooks/passport-js) to setup a custom authentication in my app. I followed the Readme and tried to test the setup locally first. I could successfully create users via Postman using the `/signup` API and also use the `/login` API to receive the token. I implemented a simple login form and tried to made a request to the `/login` API with username and password from an already created user, then I received the response with the token and saved it in the local storage to add the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` to the header. Then when I was trying to access a page where I've made a graphQL request I only got this `Error: GraphQL error: Internal Server Error`. Without using the authentication handling via the webhook, it worked without problems by using the `HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET` in the header. This I've tried yesterday. Today when I start all the servers locally like yesterday I can't even get a successful request via Postman. What's also important to mention I've added the `HASURA_GRAPHQL_AUTH_HOOK` -> `http://localhost:8081/webhook` (I removed the admin secret from the authorization header to enable the webhook) and also set permissions for the user to access the todos table like shown [here](https://learn.hasura.io/graphql/hasura/authorization/1-todos-table-permissions)

What might I be doing wrong? Here is my setup. Let me know if you need more information

This is to get the Hasura GraphQL engine and Postgres running as Docker containers, shown [here](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/getting-started/docker-simple.html) (my `docker-compose.yaml` file):

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.0.0-beta.6
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
    - "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/postgres
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: secret
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_AUTH_HOOK: http://localhost:8081/webhook
volumes:
  db_data:
```

The passport.js boilerplate project is running on `http://localhost:8081`

The hasura/graphql-engine is running on `http://localhost:8080`

The main app is running on `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: If you are using http://localhost:8081 URL inside docker, you would need to expose your Auth Webhook server at 0.0.0.0 or setup docker to run in host mode using `network_mode: host`. In case of Mac, you can replace `localhost` with `host.docker.internal` for the container to access the host machine's auth server.

Comment: Thanks @praveenweb that was one part of the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there were two issues:

1. Like [@praveenweb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4951611/praveenweb) wrote in the comments (in my case for a mac) I had to replace `localhost` with `host.docker.internal` for the container to access the host machine's auth server. So instead of `HASURA_GRAPHQL_AUTH_HOOK: http://localhost:8081/webhook` -> `HASURA_GRAPHQL_AUTH_HOOK: http://host.docker.internal:8081/webhook`
2. The reason for why I got no successful response anymore on the second day was that I totally forgot to set the `DATABASE_URL` in the environment variables like shown [here](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/tree/master/community/boilerplates/auth-webhooks/passport-js#deploy-locally). So in my case `export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/postgres`

Now everything works as expected. Hope this helps someone else too.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24319662/11067496) for more info on how to connect to localhost of host machine inside a Docker container